# Using raw input and doing calculations in python

Tags: python, input

So for part of the assignment I am doing, I ask the user their address (including street name) and minus it from 68.

so far I have:

```
streetName = raw_input("Please enter your address: ")
```

say the user enters there address as 668 Rickman Street, I am supposed to take the 668 and minus it from 68 and what would be printed is
"your secret code is -600"

-600 being obviously the calculation of 68-668 
However I do not know how to take the 668 out of the raw input and put it into the calculation.

Comment: You could split the string on `" "`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check and try to cast each splitted string if you are sure you have spaces between your number and street name

```
streetName = raw_input("Please enter your address: ")
names = streetName.split(' ')
secret_code = -1
for name in names :
    try :
        secret_code = 68 - int(name)
    except ValueError :
         continue


# Thanks to Jon Clements
if secret_code > 68 :
    print 'something went wrong , check your address'
else
    print secret_code
```

Comment: How do you tell the difference between a legitimate `secret_code` of `0` and never finding a house number?

Comment: we can set it to negative value for example , I think nobody uses negative numbers as house numbers ? :D

Answer (score 0):

You can go through `streetName` using a `for` loop and stop wherever you find the first space, store the index and extract a substring starting in 0 to the index calculated, then parse it to integer.
Example Code:

```
stringVar = "123 Hello world"
subStringVar = a[0:3]
stringParsed = int(subStringVar)
```

So now `stringParsed` is `123`, then just do a simple operation `68 - stringParsed`.

Answer (score 0):

you can split the input string on whitespace delimiter:

```
>>> int("668 Rickman Street".split()[0])
668
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the first thing to do is to understand what data structures you will use
to get to your final answer. Look out for examples on string and list comprehension.

Lets say street_name is a string. If the address occurs in the same index in street_name then you can exit the loop once you have accessed the first word or encountered the first blank space after 686.

Or you can convert the string into a list.

```
street_name_lst = street_name.split()
```

where street_name_lst => ['668', 'Rickman', 'Street']

Now you just access the first element using first index.

`address = street_name_lst[0]`

Now str_address => '686' , but this is in string(incompatible type to do any processing with an Integer type for your case), so lets convert String address 
to Integer type.

`int_add = int(str_address)`

Now you have int_add => 686 and now you can do further computation on it.

Remember data structures and type systems in any language are important.
Also look into PEP8 standard to check for good convention on naming your variables.

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id38

It might be helpful to install ipython. check http://ipython.org/